# Orthogonal projections in the spectral decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have $A=\lambda_{1}P_{\lambda_{1}}+\lambda_{2}P_{\lambda_{2}}$ with $A$ symmetric $n\times n$ matrix, $\lambda_{1}<0$ a simple eigenvalue , $\lambda_{2}> 0$ a eigenvalue with multiplicity n-1, $P_{\lambda_{i}}$ orthogonal projection onto $V_{\lambda_{i}}$ and $P_{\lambda_{1}}+P_{\lambda_{2}}=I$, can I say that $P_{\lambda_{1}}$ is a negative matrix and $P_{\lambda_{2}}$ is a positive matrix?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by positive/negative matrix? Positive/negative semidefinite matrix?

Hints:

1. A projection is orthogonal if and only if it is symmetry (over $\mathbb R$ or self-adjoint over $\mathbb C$).
2. The eigenvalues of a projection is a subset of $\{0, 1\}$.

Thus, an **orthogonal** projection is **positive semidefinite**.

Comment: Yes I mean positive/negative semidefinite matrix. Anyway thanks, so can I say that $\lambda_{1}P_{\lambda_{1}}$ is negative semidefinite matrix? Since $\lambda_{1}<0$ and $P_{\lambda_{1}}$ has as eigenvalus 0 or 1

Comment: @L.G.A.G.: yiep

Comment: sorry, but yiep means yes?

Comment: @L.G.A.G.: Yes. Sorry, a bad habit of mine.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your answer.